# Is it possible/recommended to use Solspace Freeform for a front-end user login form?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I would like to build a front-end user login form using Freeform. Is it possible or even recommended? Right now all my form input styling/markup lives inside the Freeform render templates and it would be nice to be able to use this for the login form, instead of manually using the provided example form [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s potentially possible with a custom module, but it would be far less effort (not to mention, more secure) to just apply the solspace form classes to the regular log in form.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks.